# Can anyone make grizzly-websockets-chat work under standalone grizzly?

Tags: websocket, grizzly

I'm struggling to run grizzly-websockets-chat.  I've successfully compiled the sample. HttpServer.createSimpleServer is running and serving a test index.html on localhost:8080. WebSocketEngine.getEngine().register("/chat", chatApplication) executes without complaint.  However, localhost:8080/chat returns "Resource identified by path '/chat', does not exist.".  This is not under Glassfish - just standalone Grizzly/2.2.19.

Comments in some places suggest that websocket support is off by default - I'm unable to determine how to turn it on outside of Glassfish.  I have only the test index.html in docroot.. is anything else required?

I'm not running anything special on the client side - no js, nothing.  I've not seen any such thing in the sample.  Surprisingly, I've not found a good doc or running example.  Maybe is a user problem?  ;/

Looks like websocket code may be being invoked:

```
$ java -jar ./tyrus-client-cli-1.1.jar ws://localhost:8080/chat 
# Connecting to ws://localhost:8080/chat... 
# Failed to connect to ws://localhost:8080/chat due to Handshake error
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: I've logged: https://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-1562.  I'll follow up when it's resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your request URI to ws://localhost:8080/grizzly-websockets-chat/chat.

The ChatApplication has the following defined for isApplicationRequest():

```
@Override
public boolean isApplicationRequest(HttpRequestPacket request) {
    return "/grizzly-websockets-chat/chat".equals(request.getRequestURI());
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  A colleague provided a different websocket example that is actually closer to the end-goal, so I've not pursued this further and don't know if this solution worked.  I did see this in the docs and did try it, though I clearly didn't get it right somewhere.  +1 for your response... I hope someone finds it helpful.